# Error 500 while trying to save .pdf in server using DOMPDF

Tags: php, dompdf

I have read lots of questions about this topic, but none of their solutions have been useful to me. I am trying to upload a pdf file created by DOMFILE to my server, but I get 500 error.

I have looked in my access_log and error_log but there is nothing.  I have also checked permissions through Filezilla, and they are correct (please, tell me if I have done it well):

[image]

I have made my code very simple just to focus on this problem:

```
<?php
require_once "dompdf/autoload.inc.php";

$html =
    '<html><body>'.
    '<p>Some data to be transformed to pdf.</p>'.
    '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper( "a4" , "portrait");
$dompdf->render();

$pdf = $dompdf->output();

file_put_contents("test.pdf", $pdf);
?>
```